# Parsing CSV into Pytorch tensors

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch

I have a CSV files with all numeric values except the header row. When trying to build tensors, I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytorch.py", line 14, in <module>
    test_tensor = torch.tensor(test)
ValueError: could not determine the shape of object type 'DataFrame'
```

This is my code:

```
import torch
import dask.dataframe as dd

device = torch.device("cuda:0")

print("Loading CSV...")
test = dd.read_csv("test.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")
train = dd.read_csv("train.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")

print("Converting to Tensor...")
test_tensor = torch.tensor(test)
train_tensor = torch.tensor(train)
```

Using `pandas` instead of `Dask` for CSV parsing produced the same error. I also tried to specify `dtype=torch.float64` inside the call to `torch.tensor(data)`, but got the same error again.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try converting it to an array first:

```
test_tensor = torch.Tensor(test.values)
```

Comment: Doing so results in the following error:  
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):  
      File "pytorch.py", line 11, in <module>  
        test_tensor = torch.tensor(test.values)  
    ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: I cannot get the same error here even though I have some NaNs in the dataframe. Does it come from pandas (`test.values`)? What are `test.dtypes`? Are there any int columns? It may help to change them to floats.

Answer (score 14):

I think you're just missing `.values`

```
import torch
import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
train_tensor = torch.tensor(train.values)
```

Answer (score 7):

Newer version of pandas highly recommend to use [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) instead of [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)

```py
train_tensor = torch.tensor(train.to_numpy())
```

Answer (score 1):

Only using NumPy

```
import numpy as np
import torch

tensor = torch.from_numpy(
    np.genfromtxt("train.csv", delimiter=",")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The import functions all appear to require a .csv with an array of numbers. You mentioned in your original problem case that your .csv includes column headers. Please try your code without the headers in the .csv file.